# Fill date element with border radius

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently working with bootstrap datepicker with to range windows.My task is to fill all dates in selected range. All works fine, but I have this problem:

[image: Problem]

**My CSS classes:**

```
.selected-date-picker-range{
     background-color: #0eabec!important;
     background-image:none!important;
     border-radius: 0!important;
}

.selected-start-position-date-picker {
     background-color: #2c7594!important;
     background-image: none!important;
     border-radius: 50%!important;
}

.selected-end-position-date-picker {
     background-color: #2c7594!important;
     background-image: none!important;
     border-radius: 50%!important;
}
```

How can I fill white corner spaces in active buttons? Result is have to be like this:
[image]

**I have tried this code:**

```
border-radius: 25% 0 0 25%!important;
```

But it's looks not so good. Maybe someone have some idea about that. Thanks for attention.

Comment: You may have to provide more details to get help with your specific issue. Try to provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example as described on this page here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we have enough information to go off of when trying to give you an answer.

Comment: Ok. I will do my best. I think there is enough info for some new ideas about solving problem. If not enough I try to write more.

Comment: Please post you code in jsfiddle

Comment: You could go for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/fnrfa9n7/ ... I'll play around with it and see if it's possible to get what you want without adding additional elements (by using pseudo-elements)

Comment: Ok. I will do that and add to post.

Comment: there you go: https://jsfiddle.net/fnrfa9n7/1/

Comment: even better: https://jsfiddle.net/fnrfa9n7/2/ (using `position: absolute` inside `position: relative` in order to use 100% width/height)

Comment: I'll make an answer out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This jsfiddle shows a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/fnrfa9n7/3/

The trick is to add a pseudo-element to `selected-start-position-date-picker` and `selected-end-position-date-picker` that has the same `background-color` as the `selected-date-picker-range` class, but border-radius applied only to one side of it and a `z-index` of `-1` to move it behind the round parent.

Then the pseudo-element is absolutely positioned within the relatively positioned parent, so that width and height can be 100% of the parent.

```
.selected-start-position-date-picker,
.selected-end-position-date-picker {
    position: relative;
}

.selected-start-position-date-picker:after,
.selected-end-position-date-picker:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0eabec;
}

.selected-start-position-date-picker:after {
    border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
}

.selected-end-position-date-picker:after {
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for fresh idea!

Comment: Thanks a lot once more. That worked perfectly when set to .selected-start-position-date-picker:after,
.selected-end-position-date-picker:after{ top:0; left:0};

Comment: Ok thanks for the info... I wasn't sure if top/left was needed as I thought it would be `0` by default